# FrontierLink B2B getting started

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Has anyone of you already tried integrating with FrontierLink?

Found in their documentation

**5.2 Building the FrontierLink Client** 
**5.2.1 SOAP Client Environment** 
You must adhere to the following minimum requirements for SOAP clients in order to successfully integrate with FrontierLink:

- XML 1.0
- SOAP 1.1
- HTTP 1.0 (1.1 preferred)
- SSL based connection authenticated via X.509 Digital Certificates
- WSDL1.1

A Web Services toolkit supporting WSDL 1.1 is recommended to aid your development.

In their documentation there is no sample on how to get started. I am really sorry for asking this question but what would be the code for connecting to FrontierLink? Thanks! Hoping for someone who can help :) Thank you once again!

Comment: In which language do you want to consume this web service?

Answer (score 0):

**May you please show us an example of the FrontierLink API?** so that I may be able to help you further?

Just in a nutshell with what I understand when using SOAP api, you will have to call the APIs or links from your application(web/mobile) and in turn the API will return data in form of XML. you will then have to parse that data so that you may able to use that in your application.